# Error when serve Django 1.8 Applications with Apache2 and mod_wsgi on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, linux, django, apache, ubuntu

I am trying to serve my django project with Apache2 and mod_wsgi and I am stuck. Everything works fine until I try to integrate mod_wsgi. I am using python 3. The relevant coding are as below:

---

### Apache2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin myemail@example.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite

        Alias /static/ /var/www/mysite/static/

        <Directory /var/www/mysite/static>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>


        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py


        <Directory /var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py>
        <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
        </Files>
        </Directory>

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

---

### wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

---

### Error log

```
[Mon Aug 03 18:45:42.192589 2015] [:error] [pid 2638:tid 140604829079296] [client 130.102.158.21:49084]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
[Mon Aug 03 18:45:42.192606 2015] [:error] [pid 2638:tid 140604829079296] [client 130.102.158.21:49084]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
[Mon Aug 03 18:45:42.192623 2015] [:error] [pid 2638:tid 140604829079296] [client 130.102.158.21:49084]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Mon Aug 03 18:45:42.192649 2015] [:error] [pid 2638:tid 140604829079296] [client 130.102.158.21:49084] ImportError: No module named 'mysite'
```

---

I know it has something to do with how wsgi was configured in apache2.conf file, but have no idea how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Try to add this to your wsgi.py: import sys  sys.path.append('path to you site').

Answer (score 3):

You need to add this:

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/mysite
```

From the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/), *"The WSGIPythonPath line ensures that your project package is available for import on the Python path; in other words, that import mysite works."*

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I've also used the WSGIDaemonProcess. It is now working a charm.